# CSS with divs and divs on a box?

Tags: html, css

I can't find my mistake in my CSS. The two buttons I want to create, should have 5px margin. But the button is too far away. Where is my mistake?

```
.box{
    background-color: #dcdcdc;
    border:;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-right:5%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-top: 10%;
    min-width: 50%;
    max-height: 60%;
    overflow:auto;
    display: inline-block;

}

.buttons{
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid; 
    border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
    padding:5px;
    border-right-color: #dcdcdc;
    background-color: #dcdcdc;
    margin-top: 11%;
    margin-left: 30%;
    max-width: 8%;
    min-width: 5%;
    float:left;
    min-height: 3%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.buttons2{
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid; 
    border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
    padding:5px;
    border-right-color: #dcdcdc;
    background-color: #dcdcdc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 30%;
    max-width: 8%;
    min-width: 5%;
    min-height: 3%;
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Can anyone help me? ;)
Thank you for your attention.

edit: the html is not very interesting :

```
<div class="box">
<p><b>Übersicht:</b></p>
<p>Hallo $username! Welches Quiz möchtest du heute starten?</p>
<p>Kategorie:</p>
<p>Übung:</p>

</div>

<div class="buttons">
Test
</div>

<div class="buttons2">
Test2
</div>
```

Here is an image:

[image]

Comment: Please make fiddle OR share code

Comment: first of all remove  `float:left` have a look at DEMO. http://jsbin.com/quturazu/1/edit

Comment: please add a screenshot with the desired result.

Comment: image added for you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-arranged your HTML to put the buttons first. I gave them a container named `.buttonContainer` that floats against the `.box`. And I gave the two buttons the same class.

HTML

```
<div class="buttonContainer" >
    <div class="buttons">
        Test
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
        Test2
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <p><b>Übersicht:</b></p>
    <p>Hallo $username! Welches Quiz möchtest du heute starten?</p>
    <p>Kategorie:</p>
    <p>Übung:</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box{
    padding:5px;
    background-color: #dcdcdc;  
    border-radius: 15px;
    min-width: 50%;
    max-height: 60%;
    overflow:auto;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}

.buttons{    
    padding:5px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid; 
    border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
    border-right-color: #dcdcdc;
    background-color: #dcdcdc;
    display:block;
    width:auto;
    margin-top:15px;
}

.buttonContainer{
    float:left;
}
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/L5gmk/3/

Answer (score 0):

Change Your CSS

```
.buttons{
border-width: 2px;
border-color: black;
border-style: solid; 
border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
padding:5px;
margin:5px;
border-right-color: #dcdcdc;
background-color: #dcdcdc;
max-width: 8%;
min-width: 5%;
float:left;
min-height: 3%;
display: inline-block;
}

.buttons2{
border-width: 2px;
border-color: black;
border-style: solid; 
border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
padding:5px;
border-right-color: #dcdcdc;
background-color: #dcdcdc;
margin: 5px;
max-width: 8%;
min-width: 5%;
min-height: 3%;
float:left;
display: inline-block;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NSEYq/)

Answer (score 0):

**CSS :**

```
.buttons{
border-width: 2px;
border-color: black;
border-style: solid; 
border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
padding:5px;
margin:3px;
border-right-color: #dcdcdc;
background-color: #dcdcdc;
max-width: 8%;
min-width: 5%;
min-height: 3%;
display: inline-block;
}

.buttons2{
border-width: 2px;
border-color: black;
border-style: solid; 
border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
padding:5px;
border-right-color: #dcdcdc;
background-color: #dcdcdc;
margin: 3px;
max-width: 8%;
min-width: 5%;
min-height: 3%;
display: inline-block;
}
```

it will try this.

Comment: sry it doesn t work :/ but thank u for the answer :)